# Should I use "when" or "where" in this sentence?

Tags: when, where

I am glad to have met you on Wednesday last week **where** we discussed...

OR:

I am glad to have met you on Wednesday last week **when** we discussed...

Answer (score 3):

Since the context identifies the meeting entirely in terms of *when* it occurred, and not at all in terms of where it was (my office, your office, the pub, wherever), *when* is far more directly applicable—though *where* would not be jarringly inappropriate.