# Might the use of the word "where" be inapt in these three sentences?

Tags: word-usage

The question found [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/186082/should-i-use-when-or-where-in-this-sentence) triggered a question in my mind. Lately I've been noticing how people tend to use the word *where* in a way which to me seems inapt. Some examples:

> - Anorexia is a condition *where* a person, usually a young female, has such a poor body image that she virtually starves herself to death.
> - A phobia is *where* you have a fear of, say, clowns, and this fear seemingly has no rational basis.
> - The abused dog suffered from hypothermia, a condition *where* the body's core temperature drops to a near-fatal level.

Wouldn't the words *in which* (or *when*, in the case of the hypothermic dog) be a better fit than *where* in the first and third examples?

> - Anorexia is a condition in which a person . . ..
> - The abused dog suffered from hypothermia, a condition in which . . .. Or, The abused dog suffered from hypothermia, a condition *when* . . ..

Wouldn't the word *when*, or the words *a condition in which*, be a better fit than *where* in the second example?

> - A phobia is when . . .. Or, A phobia is a condition in which . . ..

I'm not suggesting my substitutions are necessarily the best or that they exhaust the number of possibilities, but isn't the use of the word *where* inapt in my examples? If so, why? If not, why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usage of [where](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Where):

> - It was formerly considered incorrect to use where as a substitute for *in which* after a noun which did not refer to a place or position, but this use has now become acceptable: we now have a situation where/in which no further action is needed

Source: Collins English Dictionary

Comment: I was mulling over whether to closevote as "Subjective" (sounds like a peeve), but I'll just upvote this instead! Nicely found.

Comment: It is a [location metaphor](http://patthomson.wordpress.com/2013/01/17/location-another-metaphor-for-writing-about-your-research/). (I think John Lawler is away on holiday.)

Comment: While it may formerly have been **considered** incorrect by certain people (whose rigid and baseless rules for grammar should in general be disregarded) the actual **use** of *where* in cases like this seems to have been relatively common at least as far back as the beginning of the 19th century. From *Pride and Prejudice*, by Jane Austen: *"But in general and ordinary cases between friend and friend, where one of them is desired by the other to change a resolution of no very great moment …"*

Comment: I accept Collins's verdict, but I do not like the way they phrase their explanation. I would phrase it: "Formerly considered incorrect, the substitution of "where" for "in which," after a noun not referring to a place or position, has now become acceptable: we now have a situation where/in which no further action is needed." I have trouble with "It was formerly considered." The "It" is superfluous, and the locution "was formerly considered" seems to me to be as inapt as saying, "Officer Bill was formerly a sergeant in the NYPD." Either "he was a sergeant" or "he is a former sergeant."

Answer (score 1):

As it were, *where* is semantically incorrect in all of these situations. Let me explain.

In every definition of *where*, the word refers to place, situation, or condition. The latter two are actually the destination of an action (as much of a destination as an action can have!). While *where* is used informally quite often in this situation, it is still wrong. Let me now explain the correct substitute for each of your sentences.

> Anorexia is a condition where a person...

In which is, of course, the correct substitution for this situation, and the grammatical reason for this is easy to understand without explanation needed.

> A phobia is where you have a fear of...

*When* is not, in fact, the correct substitution in this case. When refers to a specific time, and since a phobia itself is not a time, then when does not work. Therefore, we should say "A phobia is a condition in which..."

> The abused dog suffered from hypothermia, a condition where...

*When* is not the correct substitution here either. A condition in itself is not a time, and therefore we must use in which again.

TL;DR:

*Where* and *When* are not appropriate in any of these situations (except informally, or as a metaphor!). Where should only apply to a place or a situation/condition. When should only apply to a time or circumstance. In which should only apply to objects.

If you need any more information, just ask! I'm happy to help.

Comment: So all metaphors are 'wrong'? I'm sorry; the people at Collins have put in more work researching the acceptability of metaphorical 'where' than you. Hence the downvote.

Comment: Metaphors are not wrong. I will duly add that to the answer, I can't believe I forgot about metaphorical usage. I apologise for my inept neglect.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Also, do note that I did not ever say that metaphors were wrong. I simply forgetfully omitted researching metaphorical usage. My answer was inclined toward explaining *why* "in which" was the correct formal substitution in those situations, metaphorical implications aside.

Comment: I note that you said 'Where and When are not appropriate in any of these situations'. They're _often_ used metaphorically. And you start off with a statement mentioning incorrectness. Yes, you mitigate 'incorrect' with 'semantically', but the tenor is still towards there being something wrong with the usages. Josh61 gives a good answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I concede, I see that the downvote was perfecly called for.

Answer (score -1):

> Anorexia is a condition *where* a person...

To my ears *where* sounds wrong here, but *whereby* would be acceptable.

I'm guessing that use of *whereby* has turned into use of *where* over time.

On the other hand,

> A phobia is *where* you have a fear of...

cannot be fixed by simply substituting *whereby*, unless you say something like *is a condition whereby*...

Comment: See wiktionary's *[whereby](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whereby#Adverb)* “Usage notes”:  

“Use of whereby as a formal equivalent of where is nonstandard and is avoided by careful speakers and writers, who use where or in which instead. The term typically fails readability and comprehension review so it is generally avoided in published works.”  -1

Comment: @jwpat7: Who's proposing to use "*whereby* as formal equivalent of *where*"? My post says something quite different: neither is a substitute for the other; they are **not equivalent**. For the rest, the text you cite just makes the point that *whereby* is no longer well known / recognized. My point was not to use *whereby* but that **such** uses of *where* might well occur because *whereby* (which would be correct) was replaced by *where* (which is not, here).

Comment: The last sentence seemed to say whereby would work

Comment: @jwpat7 Not clear to me what you are saying. The last sentence of my post says that you **cannot** fix the *A phobia is where...* phrase by simply substituting *whereby* for *where*. But you **can** fix it by saying *A phobia is a condition whereby...* That "works", AFAIK.